# How do I return _Id from $scope.db.save() in Angular and Mongo?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I need to use the id the document that I've just saved in my mongo DB as a parameter in a route. How would I return the _id of the last saved document?

Here's my code. I'm using Angular js.

```
$scope.createGroup = function(newGroup){
      $scope.groups.save(newGroup);
      $state.go('groups.invite-users',{groupId: ????})
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `save` will return a promise as it's probably using angulars `$http` service, and the resolved promise would get the id of the newly created group, so I would do as follows:

```
$scope.createGroup = function(newGroup){
    $scope.groups.save(newGroup).then(function(newGroupId) {
        $state.go('groups.invite-users',{groupId: newGroupId})
    });
};
```

Anyhow, you should provide more code (The relevant code where you create the new entry in your db for example).